# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. wile installing chatterbot

Tags: visual-studio, pip, build-tools, chatterbot

I wanted to install chatterbot library. When executing pip install chatterbot, I encountered the following error and am not able to resolve it even after installing Microsoft C++ Build Tools.

I was using windows 10 and later on updated it to windows 11 still the error is same.
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image3]
[image: image 4]

Comment: Which version of VS do you _have_ installed? MsBuild 14.0 comes with VS2019 IIRC.